# Using Cypress to test website but can't get past google 2 factor authentication

Tags: cypress, ui-automation, multi-factor-authentication

I'm new to Cypress but I'm having trouble getting past the 2-factor system that my company uses.  Cypress launches a new browser i.e. Chrome or Edge but it's always asking me to authenticate by putting in my work email and then asking for the RSA token from an app on my phone.  How can I get past this so I can test the website?

[email login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCQK9.jpg)

[RSA token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDrkJ.jpg)

Comment: You can read thru [this](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/testing-strategies/google-authentication#Setting-Google-app-credentials-in-Cypress) documentation for google authentication.

Comment: Find a way to run the app in a test environment without 2FA.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.